# How to include my modules on vscode with fortran

Tags: visual-studio-code, fortran

I want to include my modules in fortran source codes on **vscode**.

I installed **Modern Fortran** and **FORTRAN IntelliSense**.

This is the source code *main.f*.

```
      PROGRAM MAIN
C
      use mymod  !error
C
```

*mymod.f90* is in the same folder to *main.f*.

I don't know how to set the path of this module.

The error text is the below.

**Cannot open module file 'mymod.mod' for reading at (1): No such file or directory**

I would appreciate your advice.
Thank you.

Comment: How are you compiling the code? Is the module compiled.succesfuly? Youbmust compile it first. It may not be popular, but I strongly recommend learning the compiler from the command line. At least for just two source lines.

Comment: To add upon @VladimirFГероямслава, the Fortran `module` mechanism is quite different from an `include`: the content of an include file is inserted where the `include` line is, then the code is compiled. The `include` file is never compiled on its own. Whereas the source of a Fortran module (`mymod.f90` here) has to be compiled first: the compilation generates a `mymod.mod` file that is needed when the compiler encounter the line `use mymod` in `main.f90`

Comment: Thanks your advices. Sorry, I didn't know to compile the file for module! At first I will try to create the module file, mymod.mod.

Comment: You don't have to feel sorry!

Comment: For such simple case you can just do a single compiler command `gfortran module.f90 main.f90`. Even for many more files it is often possible.